# Opening a Text File which includes an int var Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a piece of Java code that will take input from the user and save a text file.
This text file have the same base name, but is saved with an int var at the end
(i.e "testDoc" + intVar + ".txt";)
Now I want to allow the user to open this file in the cmd Terminal (running windows) by entering the int variable number.
I'm new to the BufferedReader class, and am trying to figure it out. 
Here's an example of my code:

```
public static void call(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of the event you'd like to view");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\...\\event" + num + ".txt";
    String line = null;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
    }
}
```

I want to keep this simple, as it should be easy to run and quickly input/call an event.
If there's a way, I'd love the will! Thank you :)

Comment: I've edited the code to how it should look, but I don't see anything wrong with what you are trying to do

Comment: This is a snippit of the code, including only the portion meant to retrieve the text file. I have another method designed to save the text file. @MackTank

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Again, this code will execute fine.  What is the problem?

Comment: Check access permissions to txt files . Code seems to be correct,

Comment: The errors are gone, and the text files are saving and opening smoothly. Thank you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you should use readAllLines instead BufferedReader
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29

and string.format for forming a path
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html